# Is it possible to update pagelayout after upload a file using sharepoint rest api

Tags: sharepoint-webservice

Hi I uploaded a file using sharepoint rest api using below url

```
_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/Pages')/files/add(url='Pages/14789564.aspx')
```

If you see here Page Layout created as empty. Is it possible to update or create pagelayout
here

Can any one help me onthis
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise on using the pnp/sp library (if you're developing in JS/TS) and leverage the clientside pages api.

From a purely technical standpoint, you'll find two columns in the SharePoint Pages Library that contains information pertaining a page rendering/appearance/contents: `CanvasLayout1` and `LayoutWebpartsContent`, both contains a sort of XML with escaped JSON within. You may reverse engineer existing pages to try and generate your own